# How to run js with redirect_to url in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to redirect_to a second url if the first url doesn't work through controller. 
I want to add js code in a function and call the function in `redirect_to :js => {"my_function();"}, url` controller. I am not sure is it possible to do it or is there any other way to do it.

```
<script>
    function onClick(){
        console
     window.location.replace('//');
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.replace('//');
​
    },3000);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: May be should use request.referer(which would be same as window.location) instead of passing the javascript. Which is not what redirect_to is meant for anyways. redirect_to takes a url not a response.

Comment: @sethi not all browsers pass `request.referrer` including some of the more popular ones. If you want to reliably track the user through your application you need to use a cookie (eg the session).

Comment: @max all browser are supporting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer ... for the original question may be use render js: <javascript-code>

Comment: @sethi no. That compatibility chart means that the browser is merely compatible with the API - it does not mean that they send the referral.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: @max I may be you are right..do you have an example of  a browser which does not send that in any case?

Comment: @sethi I did some research and most of major browsers today send http referrer headers per default in most cases. But these setting can be changed by the user and browser addons as well as things like security/privacy tools included in major antivirus packages. For examples of browsers that don't send them at all you have privacy focused browsers like Brave and Epic.